# How to not put everything in the Wrapper component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

I want to accomplish the following task:

I have a video playing, for example Harry Potter. I also have a video recorder, where the user can record herself with her webcam. I want to have a list of user recordings, each annotated with the time of Harry Potter the recording was made at (i.e. User A made this recording at minute 32 of Harry Potter).

My first try: Have three components: `VideoRecorder`, `VideoPlayer` and `Wrapper`. Wrapper is the parent component and holds the other two. I started making VideoRecorder. It needs a few functions, since it has to start/stop the recording and handle the callbacks when the web worker is done with processing the videostream and has a data blob available. But it's fine, the component is not to heavy and relatively self-contained. When a new recording is available it informs `Wrapper` using a callback, and Wrapper adds the recording to a list.

Now the problem comes in. I need the time of the Video in `VideoPlayer`. It would not be very react-y to just access the video tag in `VideoPlayer` from `VideoRecorder`. So I move all of the logic from `VideoRecorder` up to wrapper. `VideoRecorder` becomes a pretty small controlled component, it makes callbacks on `VideoRecordingStart` and `VideoRecordingStop` to `Wrapper` and Wrapper takes care of the rest.

Now I need the time of the video in wrapper. Again, just getting the video state from its child component, is not very react-y. In the child component I could access it with video.currentTime. But that is state, and it is react-y to push up the changes of state from `VideoPlayer` to `Wrapper`. Now I am calling a callback in `VideoPlayer` each time the frame changes (or maybe a bit less), to inform `Wrapper` about where I am currently at. Wrapper now also handles the state of the video (or at least the time the video is currently at).

**I have a strong gut feeling that I have to be doing something wrong.**

All I needed was to call video.currentTime in `onStartRecording`, and that let me from a few nicely sized, relatively self-contained components to one huge wrapper component with very slim controlled child components. In fact they are so slim that I am asking myself why I am having them as components and passing in all the callbacks, instead of just including the corresponding JSX directly into the return of `Wrapper`.

I'd appreciate any help on how this should be done.

Comment: You can use React refs to attach to DOM elements. Pass a ref (either as a named prop or using `forwardRef`) from parent to child for the child to attach to the video element. Now you are close to being able to "query" the video DOM node via the attached ref externally. I say you are close because the next steps *depend* on the component implementation of the `VideoPlayer` component (class-based vs functional). You are correct in the Lifting State Up aspects of your app structure though. Please update your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible code example.